# Struts mapping to action named with extension does not work

Tags: java, tomcat, url, struts2, mapping

I am using Struts 2.3 with Tomcat 7. How does Tomcat work with struts2 when filtering request?

When I set Struts action name to something with an extension, it does not work.

```xml
<action name="login.html">
    <result>/WEB-INF/content/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

There isn't a static file like `login.html`, then why tomcat wouldn't let Struts handle the request.

When I access the url `login.html`, tomcat returns 404 page.

When I change the action name to something without extension, such as `login`, then tomcat returns the result page.

The `web.xml` is like this:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I didn't set the constant `struts.action.excludePattern`.
I cannot figure out how tomcat and Struts do this url mapping thing.

I set this at the end of my `struts.xml` to handle unmapped urls.

```xml
<action name="**">
    <result>/index.html</result>
</action>
```

When there are static files there, tomcat would use the static files as response rather than let Struts map the request to this dummy wildcard action.

I suppose that Tomcat wouldn't use the Struts filter when there exists a static file.

But it still confuses me why Struts does not handle URL with extensions when there aren't any static files under the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Struts handles URLs with action extensions. But extensions are defined in the configuration constant

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=",,action"/>
```

You can add your own action extension there. You should use the action name *without* extension, so it will less confuse.

The default action mapper is used to parse URL, and everything after *last dot* is an extension. If it matches the extensions given by the configuration above then it will extract the action name. The action name is *not* supposed to have an extension.

Comment: hello, should I add this in struts.xml file?is there any way to add it to web.xml?